# MySQL one-to-many sub-table join query appears duplicate data

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I'm doing a `select` in MySQL with a three-table `join`
(shown in the lower right quadrant of the below image). 
Relevant data in the tables are shown along the left side. 
The result is in the upper right quadrant. 
(Focus on the things in the red boxes.)

[image]

My ideal result is two rows of data, but I'm getting four. 
I don't know why there are four rows of data.

Comment: These "duplicates" are NOT duplicates! Because some field values differs. If you want "one record in output for each record in first table" then you must use a subquery instead second table which groups the data and selects one record per group by referenced fieldset.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what @Akina seems to be saying:

Your situation seems to be something like this:

Table A

```
id | (other fields)
65 |     (data)
 ︙   (more data)
```

Table B

```
id | color | (other fields)
65 | red   |     (data)
65 | blue  |        ︙
 ︙   (more data)
```

Table C

```
id | animal | (other fields)
65 | cat    |     (data)
65 | dog    |        ︙
 ︙     (more data)
```

and you’re joining the three tables on the `id` field.
Assuming that there are no other `id` matches than `65`,
you can expect to get

```
id | color | animal | (other fields)
65 | red   | cat    |     (data)
65 | red   | dog    |       ︙
65 | blue  | cat    |       ︙
65 | blue  | dog    |       ︙
```

In general, if you have *N* matching rows in Table B
and *M* matching rows in Table C,
you can expect to have *N* × *M* rows in the join.